# Ed25519 and sealed boxes libsodium

Tags: elliptic-curves, ed25519, libsodium

Accidentally used ed25519 public key to create libsoidum_sealed_box. Is there any way to decrypt the data if the private key ed25519 is known?

Comment: I think, the receiver is already can decrypt without your private key.

Comment: can you explain little bit ?